# Print Content In RichTextBox with Image Paste Inside

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2010, vba, barcode-printing

I have problem to print the content (text and barcode image) inside the RichTextBox. 
I want to loop print image and text.

Here is my richtextbox.
[image: Text with barcode image]

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CreateBarcode_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CreateBarcode.Click
  RichTextBox1.AppendText("TEMPORARY MRN - HOSPITAL  " & vbNewLine & "  MRN   : AE - " &    Sum.ToString & vbNewLine)
  AxBarcode1.Refresh()

  Dim img As Image = AxBarcode1.Picture
  Dim orgData = Clipboard.GetDataObject
  Clipboard.SetImage(img)
  Me.RichTextBox1.Paste()
  RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbNewLine & "  Name  : " & vbNewLine & "  Ic No : " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
End Sub


Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

  RichTextBox1.AppendText("TEMPORARY MRN - HOSPITAL  " & vbNewLine & "  MRN   : AE - " &    Sum.ToString & vbNewLine)
  Dim font As New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
   e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 10, 10)
  AxBarcode1.Refresh()

  Dim img As Image = AxBarcode1.Picture
  Dim orgData = Clipboard.GetDataObject
  Clipboard.SetImage(img)
  Me.RichTextBox1.Paste()
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 15, 15)
  RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbNewLine & "  Name  : " & vbNewLine & "  Ic No : " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
  e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 10, 10)

End Sub
```

Here is the output result:

[image]

Thanks and appreciate for any help :)

Comment: You want to know how to insert picture or picture is already inserted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The picture is already inserted, I want to print all the text and picture, but only text printed not the picture..how to print text and picture?